# Why does this HTML page with single A4 page ratio spans over 2 pages in Chrome or Firefox Print (not Safari?)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, printing

I would like to understand the conditions that lead to the generated PDF from the provided HTML source code spanning over 2 pages and what to do to prevent this.

### Goal

From **n div of correct A4 ratio**, I am able to generate a PDF of **n pages** without overflow on any additional page.

### Steps to reproduce the problem

1. Open the HTML page with the source code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Red Div</title>
    <style>
        .red-div {
            width: 1240px;
            height: 1753px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="red-div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML page has a width / height ratio of 1/sqrt(2) as per standard page ratio specs. The width of the main div is 1240px and height is 1753px defined by CSS.
[image: Computer CSS Layout of the element]
2. Open it using Chrome or Firefox.
3. Hit CTRL+P to open the PDF printing preview, set the A4, scale 100% (or default), no margins, print background = true.
4. The preview spans over 2 pages.[image]

### Additional comments

- Reducing the scale to 96% fits the HTML page is one page.
- This issue does NOT occur on Safari.
- I have raised this issue on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1499618, which ended in in won't fix without explanation of why it happens.

Comment: I don't think Chrome is scaling it down yet other browsers are. Hence why it works when you manually set the scaling to 96%. You should consider defining `.red` in millimetres instead `width:210mm; height:297mm;`

Comment: Thanks @Moob. Unfortunately your suggested solution would only apply to A4 (I did not mentioned it) and most importantly the platform I am using only works in px (or %), so unfortunately that would not be suitable.

Comment: Since you know that it is too big and needs scaling to 96% why not pre-scale it in CSS? `red-div{transform: scale(0.96);}`

Answer (score 1):

Print to PDF has its own controls so your page should work if you pre-set the page. Chrome /Edge "Save As" or "Print to MS printer" should make no difference.

[image]
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Red Div</title>
    <style>
     @media print { @page { margin: 0; size: 1240px 1753px ; } body { margin: 0; } }
        .red-div {
            width: 1240px;
            height: 1753px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="red-div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However Firefox uses a different system !!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @K J for your input! But Say I have several divs, each of them is width: 1240px; height: 1753px;. How does this print control work with several pages (one div = one page)?